# How to lookup the value of a variable based on the value of other variable via the EL Expression language

Tags: jsp, jstl

Let's say I've got two request attributes coming:

1. "fieldnames" which is a list of field names.  example: ["fielda", "fieldb"]
2. "field.fielda" which contains a snippet of html.  example: an input field or something like that

In my JSP page I've got something like the following:

```
<c:forEach var="field" value="${fieldnames}">
  <c:set var="tmp" value="field.${field}"/>
  ${request.getAttribute(tmp)}
</c:forEach>
```

Now the problem, I can see the name of the field via the list.  I can generate in a temp variable the "proper" field name.  But I can't figure out how to get the value of the referenced attribute from the request attribute map.  Can this be done?  I've tried using the request[variable] notation as well to no avail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you have a bean like:

```
public class MyBean {
   private String fielda;
   private String fieldb;

   public String getFielda() {
      return fielda;
   }
   public void setFielda(String fielda) {
      this.fielda = fielda;
   }
   public String getFieldb() {
      return fieldb;
   }
   public void setFieldb(String fieldb) {
      this.fieldb = fieldb;
   }
}
```

with code somewhere that does:

```
MyBean field = new MyBean();
field.setFielda("Message from A");
field.setFieldb("Message from B");
request.setAttribute("field", field);

request.setAttribute("fieldnames", new String[] { 
   "fielda", "fieldb" 
});
```

then something like this should work:

```
<c:forEach var="fn" items="${fieldnames}">
   ${requestScope.field[fn]}
</c:forEach>
```

If that fails, or your code is more complex than that, you could pull out the logic in   [a custom tag](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/bnalj.html) or [a custom function](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/bnahq.html#bnaio) to do the [EL evaluation](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/1.4/api/javax/servlet/jsp/JspContext.html#getExpressionEvaluator%28%29). If that's too much overhead for the situation, then maybe you could rethink your code and find another way for obtaining the same result.

Comment: That's what I ended up doing (custom tag).  It'd be nice if there were a cleaner mechanism in EL for this however.

Comment: @erehwon: Kinda late... but it just occurred to me that for this case there is a simpler solution than my initial one. See the updated answer.